# what is the udev rule to allow specific vendor thumb drive?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I need a `udev` rule so that it should detect the vendor of the USB pendrive, and allow only specific vendors, rejecting all others.

1. How to write such a rule ?
2. Where should the rules be placed `/etc/udev/rules.d` or `/lib/udev/rules.d/`
3. What is the command to get effect of the `udev` rule.

urgent plz

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the output from `dmesg` or the files in `/sys` to detect the right vendor and model of your device. After you have those, writing a udev rule for the device is trivial. For example, this is the rule I use for my Apple iPod (written to `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-ipod.rules`):

```
ATTRS{serial}=="0000000000000000", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Apple Inc.", ATTRS{product}=="iPod", KERNEL=="sd?1", SYMLINK+="ipod", GROUP="plugdev", MODE="0660"
```

This creates a `/dev/ipod` symlink to the first partition of a SCSI disk device with the defined serial number, from the manufacturer "Apple Inc.", with the model name "iPod".

Executing something like `udevadm control --reload-rules` and then `udevadm trigger` (depending on your platform) should rediscover and apply new rules to your device.